# Bootstrap drop-down not working in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i'm using get_template_directory but its not connecting me to the js

```
  <script src="<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

May be i'm doing it with the wrong way any suggestions?

Comment: the php is irrelevant here. check the output, the html.

Answer (score 0):

The `get_template_directory()` retrieves the absolute path to the directory of the current theme, without the trailing slash. 
whereas you need `get_template_directory_uri()` , which retrieve template directory URI for the current theme.

Try

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Note: This is not the right way to include scripts in Wordpress, use `wp_enqueue_script()` [check](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)